# What is a matrix of tuples?

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, notation, game-theory

Consider the prisoner's dilemma, in this game, you have a matrix,

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} (2,2) & (0,5) \\ (5,0) & (1,1) \end{bmatrix}$$

(or something like this)

But what is this object exactly?

Is $$A \in \mathbb{R}^{2^\mathbf{N} \times 2^\mathbb{N}}$$
I can't seem to know how to think about this object concretely.

Comment: I like the answer below, but I'd add that "matrix of pairs" is a perfectly concrete way of thinking about it. If you don't plan on multiplying boxes of numbers or pairs together, for example, (as you might in a ring, but might not if these are payoffs in a game or some such), you really aren't using much more than just the structure of that thing as a box of pairs of numbers. (Note that even a matrix of single numbers is not defined much more than as "box of numbers" in many books, although you can think of them in all sorts of other ways.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it’s a member of $(\Bbb R^2)^{2\times 2}$. If $A$ is some ring, $A^{2\times 2}$ is the set of two by two matrices with elements in $A$.

Comment: This is a very interesting take. I did not know such a set existed.